# ember-cli-selectize: Mutliselect with server side filtering

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

Could someone please provide an example how to achieve a server side filtered multiselect in Ember.js using ember-cli-selectize?

I got the multiselect working but my selection dataset includes >3500 items, so my application is slowed down.

In ember-cli-selectize there is an option "filter" but I don't know how to use it.

https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-cli-selectize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an example. See this link:

https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-cli-selectize/issues/81